# Implementation of 4-bit subtractor

Tags: comparator, adder, boolean-algebra

How to implement subtractor of two 4-bit numbers using subtractors of two 1-bit numbers as a module(no assembler coding, just expressions in boolean algebra)?
If there are four 1-bit subtractors, how to find expressions for outputs of each?

For example, 3-bit comparator implementation using 1-bit comparators gives:

```
for A2A1A0 > B2B1B0
X=(A2>B2)+(A2=B2)(A1>B1)+(A2=B2)(A1=B1)(A0>B0)=X0+Y2X1+Y2Y1X0

for A2A1A0 = B2B1B0
Y=(A2=B2)(A1=B1)(A0=B0)=Y2Y1Y0

for A2A1A0 < B2B1B0
Z=(A2<B2)+(A2=B2)(A1=B1)(A0<B0)=Z2+Y2Z1+Y2Y1Z0
```

Truth table for full subtractor:

```
A B Ci R Co
0 0 0  0 0
0 0 1  1 1
0 1 0  1 1
0 1 1  0 1
1 0 0  1 0
1 0 1  0 0
1 1 0  0 0
1 1 1  1 1
```

Comment: So you are asking how to derive a boolean function from a truth table? If so, I think you need to get back to the books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these example I have shown an example of implementing 1bit subtractor using 2-2bit subtractor. 
In this image we have implemented 1bit subtractor and module using 4:1 mux,
and I have implemented 2-2bit subtractor using same module.

[image]

I hope these information helps you.